# android menuItem text change

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, menuitem

I'm trying to change the menuitem's title at app startup based on whether the user is registered or not, but I get this error :

```
Process: com.cloud.services, PID: 25186
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.cloud.services/com.cloud.services.MainActivity}: 
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2345)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5315)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:736)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference
    at com.cloud.services.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:35)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5933)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2298)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2405) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:149) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1324) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:211) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5315) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:941) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:736)
```

My MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

private SectionsPageAdapter mSectionsPageAdapter;
private FirebaseAuth auth;
private Menu menu;
private ViewPager mViewPager;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
        item.setTitle("LogOut");
    }


    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.loginmenu, menu);
    return true;
}
//and this to handle actions
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        if (item.getTitle().equals("Login\SignUp**strong text**")){
        Intent intent4 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent4);}
        else{
            auth.signOut();
        }
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the Android Lifecycle, `onCreate()` is called first before the menu is inflated. Hence, referencing the menu item in your `onCreate()` method will cause your app to crash because the menu has not been inflated yet. That's why you're getting this:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'android.view.MenuItem android.view.Menu.findItem(int)' on a null object reference
```

To fix this, simply overriding `onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)` which is called once when the option menu is opened, and move your login logic check into that method. Like this:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    MenuItem item= menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings);
    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        item.setTitle("LogOut");
    }
  return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**Edit**: Also, `menu` will be null since you're not assigning anything to it. Consequently, calling `findItem(id)` on it will crash your app. Remove the global `menu` from your code as adding the `onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu)` will make it redundant in this case.

If you need further clarification on this, please let me know in the comment section.